# SQL Sum up until one column is equal to or greater than other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have five fields in a temp table called #ClaimsTemp3:
AMTPAY, YMDPAID, CARRIER, PAYTO, DIVISION_NBR, AMTPAY2 and YMDPAID2

AMTPAY is a negative number.  For every combination of AMTPAY, YMDPAID, CARRIER, PAYTO, and DIVISION_NBR there are several rows of AMTPAY2 and YMDPAID2:

```
AMTPAY  YMDPAID   CARRIER PAYTO   DIVISION  AMTPAY2 YMDPAID2   
-300    20120101    04    O900    123456    50      20120201

-300    20120101    04    O900    123456    25      20120202

-300    20120101    04    O900    123456    10      20120203
```

I need to report when the sum of AMTPAY2 reaches the number in AMTPAY (except to the positive instead of negative) for a particular DIVISION_NBR and PAYTO combination.  So when the AMTPAY2 reaches 300 for CARRIER 04 and DIVISION 123456, I need to show that record.  The nuances of this are also that it might not be an exact match, for instance (in the example above), on 20120204 there was an AMTPAY2 of 250.  Now I want to see it in the query, just for that week (YMDPAID2), when it met or exceeded the negative balance.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for both AMTPAY and AMTPAY2 fields:

```
SELECT SUM(TBLB.AMTPAY) AS Total,TBLB.YMDPAID FROM #ClaimsTemp3 AS TBLA 
INNER JOIN #ClaimsTemp3 AS TBLB ON (TBLA.YMDPAID=TBLB.YMDPAID)
WHERE TBLA.YMDPAID<=TBLB.YMDPAID
```

You should be able to figure out how to use these as a subquery to find out where the difference is.  Let me know if you need me to elucidate:

```
SELECT T1.YMDPAID FROM (subquery1) AS T1 INNER JOIN (subquery2) AS T2 WHERE T1.Total-T2.Total>0
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not completely following.  Would you be able to be a little more specific?

Comment: So, take the top query and plug that in for subquery1, then modify it for AMTPAY2, and plug that in for subquery2.  That should give you the YMDPAID of the row that meets your condition.